JAX-RS resource returns HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found after Jakarta migration
I've upgraded an 'old' (was working) EE Application with JSON which did work with 'javax'. Now on EE 10.x & Jakarta.
implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0")

Using:
import com.bewherewhen.ejb.UsersJSONEJB;

import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Named
@Path("/")
public class UsersJSONController {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/get-all-users")
    public Response getAllUsersJSON() {
        LOGGER.info(">>>>> UsersJSONController getAllUsersJSON .....");

        String json = usersJSONEJB.getAllUsersJSON();
        LOGGER.info(">>>>> 1.6 UsersJSONEJB getAllUsersJSON = {}", json);

        return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}

If I run 'curl' I get:
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/get-all-users/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080
> GET /get-all-users/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Request completely sent off
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 74
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Sun, 04 Aug 2024 17:07:07 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>404 - Not Found</body></html>

Using:

macOS Sonoma 14.6
gson 2.11.0
curl 8.9.1
WildFly Distribution - 33.0.0.Final
Jakarta EE 10.0.0 & 11.0.0-M4
JDK 21.0.2
Kotlin 2.0.0
Mojarra 4.1.0

TIA.

Could you add the import section in your sample please ?

Do you have an Application class? Does it have the correct @ApplicationPath annotation? Have you removed all the javax dependencies so you don't accidentally use them? Seems to me, if the application was working previously, then it is misconfigured for Jakarta.

@Paul Samsotha - I had removed all the 'javax' some time ago when I migrated to EE 9 (No REST). Looks like I haven't added:
@ApplicationPath("notifywell")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
public ApplicationConfig() {
}
}. TIA

Maybe the trailing slash is the cause of the error. Did you try to curl /get-all-users without / at the end of the URL (so not /get-all-users/) ?

Similar: WildFly localhost 'forbidden' access. See my in-depth Answer there, with explanation of @ApplicationPath & @Path and the URL parts, along with super-simple example code & POM.

I added 'ApplicationPath/ApplicationConfig' on 'javax':
package com.bewherewhen.webservices;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("beWhereWhen")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
    }
}

Run:
curl -v http://localhost:8080/BeWhereWhen/beWhereWhen/get-all-users/

Gives 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK":
* Host localhost:8080 was resolved.
* IPv6: ::1
* IPv4: 127.0.0.1
*   Trying [::1]:8080...
* connect to ::1 port 8080 from ::1 port 63674 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080
> GET /BeWhereWhen/beWhereWhen/get-all-users/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Request completely sent off
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 4
< Date: Tue, 06 Aug 2024 21:31:47 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

However unable to create a version for Jakarta EE 10/11:
import jakarta.faces.application.Application;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

Error with:
error: ApplicationConfig is not abstract and does not override abstract method getValidatorIds() in Application

Unable to deploy with "jakarta.ws.rs" on EE 10/11. Selected Methods to Implement on WildFly 33.0.0. Can any suggestion or examples?
Fixed:
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("beWhereWhen")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        // Default constructor
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        // Return a non-null Set of resource and provider classes
        return Set.of(); // Replace with actual resource classes if any
    }

    //@Override
    public ActionListener getActionListener() {
        // Implement the method for the action listener
        return new MyActionListener(); // Replace with your actual listener implementation
    }

    // Define MyActionListener or replace with your actual implementation
    private static class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void performSomeAction() {
            // Implement the action listener's functionality here
        }
    }

    // Define an interface if it's not already defined.
    // This is just an example. Replace it with the actual interface definition.
    private interface ActionListener {
        void performSomeAction();
    }
}

Run:
* Host localhost:8080 was resolved.
* IPv6: ::1
* IPv4: 127.0.0.1
*   Trying [::1]:8080...
* connect to ::1 port 8080 from ::1 port 49357 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080
> GET /BeWhereWhen/beWhereWhen/get-all-users HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Request completely sent off
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 14
< Date: Fri, 09 Aug 2024 16:19:36 GMT
< 
[
  {etc ...},
  {etc ...}
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

